# SQL Count of Occurence

Tags: sql, count

I have these two tables A and B

A:

```
id|name
1 | AAA
2 | BBB
3 | CCC
```

B:

```
id|a_ref_id|name2
1 |1       |aaa
2 |1       |aAa
3 |2       |bbb
4 |3       |ccc
5 |3       |cCc
```

This tables can be joined via `a_ref_id`.

I want to have a output like this:

```
A_id|A_name|B_id|B_name2|A_id_occurencse_in_this_query
1   |AAA   |1   |aaa    |1
1   |AAA   |2   |aAa    |2
2   |BBB   |3   |bbb    |1
3   |CCC   |4   |ccc    |1
3   |CCC   |5   |cCc    |2
```

The last column is my problem.

The Join is easy going but i have no idea how to get the last Column. I had tried with `COUNT`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, etc. but no luck.

Any Idea's?

Comment: Could you please share the written query? I'll change that to show you the way. You need a sub-query to do such a thing.

Comment: Sure: 
"Select * from A a Left Join B b on a.id = b.a_ref_id"

Answer (score 1):

For MS-SQL you can use a `ROW_NUMBER()` and  `PARTITION`

```
SELECT
  a.ID as A_ID,
  a.Name as A_Name,
  B.ID as B_ID,
  B.NAME2 as B_Name2,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION By A.ID ORDER BY A.ID, B.ID) as A_id_occurencse_in_this_query
FROM A
JOIN B
  ON a.ID = b.a_ref_id
```

Comment: Thx for the Answers! The problem is that i can not use DB specific SQL. I can only use standart SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from 
(select a.id , min(a_ref_id) as a_ref_id, min(name2) as name , count(1) as A_id_occurencse
from B a join B b on a.id < b.id 
group by a.id) t join A a on t.a_ref_id = a.id
```